# Java Object-Stream: Objects "change" while transmission

Tags: java, arraylist, client-server, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I am programming a client-server based sandboxgame and there is a weird bug:
The server saves all entities in an ArrayList, including the players.
It also saves an ArrayList which just contains the players, which are also included in the Entity-ArrayList.
For every tick and every player the server sends the position of the player, the list of all entities and the command to do a client-based tick. I am using Object-Output and -InputStreams for the Transmission.
The messages, which are send by the server, are looking like this:

```
-> STPOS:{help.DoublePoint@4bfb6f3b}    y-coord is 75.25017862499999, I already checked
-> SDENT:{[entity.Player@7dae94a2]}     y-coord is 75.25017862499999
-> CLTICK
```

The client-input seems like this:

```
<- STPOS: {help.DoublePoint@49411fd2}      y-coord is 75.25017862499999
<- SDENT: {[entity.Player@16f4df75]}       y-coord is 60.00158922
<- CLTICK
```

Thus the coordinate "magically" changes.

The server-output of the ArrayList works this way: (out : ObjectOutputStream, entities: ArrayList, Entity and ProtocolClass are my own classes)

```
out.writeObject(new ProtocolClass(PROTOCOL.sendEntities, entities));
```

The client-sided input follows: (in: ObjectInputStream)

```
ProtocolClass pc = (ProtocolClass) in.readObject();
[...]
[if pc.protocol equals PROTOCOL.sendEntities]
entities = (ArrayList<Entity>) pc.object;
```

The y-coord in the beginning is "60" and increases, when the player is falling to the ground. 75.25... is the coordinate he has when he touches the ground. 60.0015... is the first transmitted new y-coordinate. Thus it works for the first tick. But it's not the case all the time, often it stays at 60.

There is only one thread using one stream, so that the streams are not called asynchronly. All "Queries" are saved in a Queue. I scanned my whole project, but it really only sends the "SDENT"-Query once a tick.

I have no idea why this happens. Casting the transmitted objects to an ArrayList produces a warning in Eclipse: "Unchecked cast". In other cases of casting objects this is not the case. Only casting to ArrayList not makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` every time you want to write a revised coy of the same object. See the Javadoc for why.